# Why does my plist file exist even when I've uninstalled an app and wiped the simulator?

Tags: iphone

I am trying to detect the existence of a plist file on application start.  When my data class (descendant of NSObject) is initialized, it loads the plist file.

Before it loads, it checks to see if the file exists, and if it doesn't, it sets the data = nil instead of trying to process the array of data in the plist file.

However, every time it starts it indicates the file exists.  Even when I uninstall the app in the organizer **and** when wiping the simulator directory (iPhone Simulator/3.0/Applications).

I have the following static method in a library class named FileIO:

```
+(BOOL) fileExists:(NSString *)fileName {
    NSString *path = [FileIO getPath:fileName]; // gets the path to the docs directory
    if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:path]) return YES;
    else return NO;
}
```

In my data class:

```
//if( [FileIO fileExists:kFavorites_Filename] ) [FileIO deleteFile:kFavorites_Filename];
if ([FileIO fileExists:kFavorites_Filename]) {NSLog(@"exists");
```

The "exists" is logged every time unless I un-comment the method to delete the file.

How can the file exist if I've deleted the app?  I've deleted the simulator directory and uninstalled on the device but both say it still exists.

What gives???

Comment: I'm still unable to resolve this. It just doesn't make any sense.  The filename is "files.plist"

Answer (score 0):

This makes sense since plists stores preferences and things. Well when you restore you iPhone you delete all apps. But, if the plists are saved then your preferences are saved once you re-sintall the apps back on your iPhone.